# Error on cassandra SELECT Query with order by

Tags: cassandra

Now I'm working with Cassandra 3.11 and I encounter an error.

Below SCHEMA is my cassandra model created by Cassandra python driver.

```
CREATE TABLE motosense.collection (
    id uuid,
    created_at timestamp,
    accel_data blob,
    model_name text,
    rssi int,
    sensor_id int,
    sensor_version text,
    PRIMARY KEY (id, created_at) ) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (created_at DESC)
    AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
    AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE';
CREATE INDEX collection_sensor_id_idx ON motosense.collection (sensor_id);
```

After creating above table and execute below query,

```
SELECT id, created_at FROM calculated_collection WHERE sensor_id = 1 ORDER BY created_at DESC;
```

I get this error:

> code=2200 [Invalid query] message="ORDER BY with 2ndary indexes is not
>   supported."

When I execute query without `order by`, I get unordered data query set.
How can I solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Secondary indexes are not designed to allow multiple queries on the
>   same table. You should build another table that would satisfy your
>   query. As a secondary index query pulls back data from multiple
>   partitions, it may or may not come back in sorted order (which is why
>   ORDER BY is not allowed on secondary index queries).

The above quote is from the link below.

You should have a look on this, is the same issue - [ORDER BY with 2ndary indexes is not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25920078/order-by-with-2ndary-indexes-is-not-supported).

This is also related - [Why Secondary Index ( = ?) and Clustering Columns (order by) CANNOT be used together for CQL Query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52730925/why-secondary-index-and-clustering-columns-order-by-cannot-be-used-toge)